# How to group an array by name using pure JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here's my array:

```
const array = [
    {
        name: "kano",
        subject: "gujarati",
        marks: 99
    },
    {
        name: "kano",
        subject: "maths",
        marks: 99
    },
    {
        name: "kano",
        subject: "hindi",
        marks: 99
    },
    {
        name: "dixit",
        subject: "hindi",
        marks: 80
    },
    {
        name: "dixit",
        subject: "maths",
        marks: 80
    },
    {
        name: "dixit",
        subject: "gujarati",
        marks: 80
    },
]
```

How can I group it by name so that I would get the result of:

```
 {
    kano: {
        gujarati: 99,
        maths: 99,
        hindi: 99,
        total: 297,
        percentage: 99
    },
    dixit: {
        gujarati: 80,
        maths: 80,
        hindi: 80,
        total: 240,
        percentage: 80
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/group

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I group an array of objects by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce method to group values.

```
let output = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (!acc[item.name]) {
    acc[item.name] = { [item.subject]: item.marks };
  } else {
    acc[item.name][item.subject] = item.marks;
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

output = Object.entries(output).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  const total = Object.values(value).reduce((total, curr) => total + curr, 0);
  const percentage = total / Object.values(value).length;
  acc[key] = { ...value, total, percentage };
  return acc;
}, {});


console.log(output)
```

Comment: You do not have a computation for `total` and `percentage`.

Comment: ohh didnt see that, done

Comment: Nice. Can you convert this into a snippet and briefly explain it so I could upvote it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) were you

- Create the object with `total` and `percentage` if it doesn't exist
- Add `c.marks` to `c.subject`
- Add `c.marks` to `total`
- Overwrite `percentage` if `c.marks` is larger, otherwise, just keep it

```js
const array = [{name: "kano", subject: "gujarati", marks: 99 }, {name: "kano", subject: "maths", marks: 99 }, {name: "kano", subject: "hindi", marks: 99 }, {name: "dixit", subject: "hindi", marks: 80 }, {name: "dixit", subject: "maths", marks: 80 }, {name: "dixit", subject: "gujarati", marks: 80 }, ];

const res = array.reduce((p, c) => {
  p[c.name] = (p[c.name] || { total: 0, percentage: 0 });
  p[c.name][c.subject] = (p[c.name][c.subject] || 0) + c.marks;
  p[c.name].total += c.marks;
  p[c.name].percentage = (c.marks > p[c.name].percentage ? c.marks : p[c.name].percentage); 
  
  return p;
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

---

Instead of altering `p` as shown above, we could also instant return an object, were we spread (`...`) the new data to. Not as readable, but thought I'd share:

```js
.reduce((p, c) => ({
    ...p,
    [c.name]: {
       ...(p[c.name] || { }),
       total: (p[c.name]?.total || 0) + c.marks,
       [c.subject]: (p[c.subject] || 0) + c.marks,
       percentage: (p[c.subject]?.percentage || 0) > c.marks ? p[c.subject].percentage  : c.marks
    }
}), {});
```

```js
const res = [{name: "kano", subject: "gujarati", marks: 99 }, {name: "kano", subject: "maths", marks: 99 }, {name: "kano", subject: "hindi", marks: 99 }, {name: "dixit", subject: "hindi", marks: 80 }, {name: "dixit", subject: "maths", marks: 80 }, {name: "dixit", subject: "gujarati", marks: 80 } ]

.reduce((p, c) => ({
    ...p,
    [c.name]: {
       ...(p[c.name] || { }),
       total: (p[c.name]?.total || 0) + c.marks,
       [c.subject]: (p[c.subject] || 0) + c.marks,
       percentage: (p[c.subject]?.percentage || 0) > c.marks ? p[c.subject].percentage  : c.marks
    }
}), {});

console.log(res)
```

---

*Both* snippets generate:

```json
{
  "kano": {
    "total": 297,
    "percentage": 99,
    "gujarati": 99,
    "maths": 99,
    "hindi": 99
  },
  "dixit": {
    "total": 240,
    "percentage": 80,
    "hindi": 80,
    "maths": 80,
    "gujarati": 80
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define helper functions to `create` or `update` a student ( using spread syntax `...` to exclude student's `name`). Next, you can use ternary operator to conditionally assign a value to the student's name `key` in the `forEach` loop (uses `object destructuring` syntax). Update the student if the name exist as the key on `students` object, otherwise create new student

```js
const array = [
  { name: "kano", subject: "gujarati", marks: 99 },
  { name: "kano", subject: "maths", marks: 99 },
  { name: "kano", subject: "hindi", marks: 99 },
  { name: "dixit", subject: "hindi", marks: 80 },
  { name: "dixit", subject: "maths", marks: 80 },
  { name: "dixit", subject: "gujarati", marks: 80 },
];

const genStudentsStats = (array) => {
  const students = {};
  const create = (name, subject, marks) => ({
    name,
    total: marks,
    percentage: marks / 3,
    [subject]: marks,
  });

  const update = (student, subject, marks) => {
    const {name,...rest } = student;
    return {
      ...rest,
      [subject]: marks,
      total: student.total + marks,
      percentage: (student.total + marks) / 3,
    };
   
  };

  array.forEach(({ name,subject, marks}) => {
    students[name] ?
      (students[name] = update(students[name], subject, marks)) :
      (students[name] = create(name, subject, marks));
  });

  return students;
};


const result = genStudentsStats(array);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```js
const array = [
    {
        name: "kano",
        subject: "gujarati",
        marks: 99
    },
    {
        name: "kano",
        subject: "maths",
        marks: 99
    },
    {
        name: "kano",
        subject: "hindi",
        marks: 99
    },
    {
        name: "dixit",
        subject: "hindi",
        marks: 80
    },
    {
        name: "dixit",
        subject: "maths",
        marks: 80
    },
    {
        name: "dixit",
        subject: "gujarati",
        marks: 80
    },
];
const sbj = ['gujarati', 'maths', 'hindi'];
const res = array.reduce((acc, {name, subject, marks}) => {
    acc[name] ??= {gujarati: 0, maths: 0, hindi: 0, total: 0, percentage: 0};
    for (let i of sbj) {
        if (subject == i) acc[name][subject] = marks;
    }
    acc[name].total += marks;
    acc[name].percentage = acc[name].total / 3;
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const array = [
    {
        name: "kano",
        subject: "gujarati",
        marks: 99
    },
    {
        name: "kano",
        subject: "maths",
        marks: 99
    },
    {
        name: "kano",
        subject: "hindi",
        marks: 99
    },
    {
        name: "dixit",
        subject: "hindi",
        marks: 80
    },
    {
        name: "dixit",
        subject: "maths",
        marks: 80
    },
    {
        name: "dixit",
        subject: "gujarati",
        marks: 80
    },
];

let output = {};
for (let item of array) {
    if (!output[item.name]) output[item.name] = { [item.subject]: item.marks};
    else output[item.name][item.subject] = item.marks;
}

for (let key in output) {
    let total = 0;
    let cnt = 0;
    for (let innerKey in output[key]) {
        total += output[key][innerKey];
        cnt++;
    }
    output[key].total = total;
    output[key].precentage = total / cnt;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(output))
```

```html
<b>Expected</b>

<br>

<code>
{
    kano: {
        gujarati: 99,
        maths: 99,
        hindi: 99,
        total: 297,
        percentage: 99
    },
    dixit: {
        gujarati: 80,
        maths: 80,
        hindi: 80,
        total: 240,
        percentage: 80
    }

}
</code>

<br>

<b>Actual</b>

<br>
```

Explanation:

- we create an empty object
- we loop our initial array and in each step

  - we create the inner object by name if it did not already exist
  - we add the new key-value pair to the new inner object
- we loop our result and for each of its items

  - we create a `total` and a `cnt` variable initialized with 0
  - we loop the inner objects and

    - add its value to `total`
    - increment `cnt`
  - we store `total` as the inner object's total
  - we compute percentage and store that too